# Does SharedPreferences needs privacy policy?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I know that if you want to store data on database, you'll need a privacy policy in your app. But if I store data like email/password on SharedPreferences, do I need too?

Comment: NO you no need to the privacy policy for SharedPreferences

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about privacy policies required to launch app on play store then sharedPrefrences will not force you to provide privacy policies following are the Sensitive permissions that need a Privacy Policy. But SharedPrefrances does not require any permission

1. Camera
2. Microphone
3. Contacts
4. Calendar
5. Location
6. Sensors
7. Storage
8. Messaging
9. Phone

More than that There are three main reasons to have privacy policy:

- Multiple international laws require a Privacy Policy if any user information is collected and used by an app,
- The Google Play Store Distribution Agreement requires all apps available through the store to have a Privacy Policy in place if the app collects personal data, and
- Some app permission requests automatically trigger the requirement of a Privacy Policy by Google Play Store

Answer (score 0):

Permission requests should make sense to users. You may only request permissions that are necessary to implement critical current features or services in your application. You may not use permissions that give access to user or device data for undisclosed, unimplemented, or disallowed features or purposes.

> Following "**Dangerous**" permission groups (personal or sensitive user
>   data mentioned earlier) in privacy policy:

- CALENDAR
- CAMERA
- CONTACTS
- LOCATION
- MICROPHONE
- PHONE
- SENSORS

---

[**SharedPreferences**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) object points to a file containing key-value pairs and provides simple methods to read and write them. So, don't need to the [**Privacy Policy**](https://policies.google.com/privacy?hl=en-US) for **SharedPreferences**.